# maven sql plugin escape backslah

Tags: maven

I am having a problem seeding my data using maven SQL plugin. Because the data consist of backslash in the value of insert statement. When I run the file manually, no problem at all. The data look something like this `','7644213421\',` and the error message is

> [ERROR] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Could someone please advice me how to escape the special characters while using mvn sql plugin?

This is the maven plugin version

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
```

Comment: Does setting escapeProcessing (https://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#escapeProcessing) to false help?

Comment: Not. Still got the same error. I already switch from false to true and true to false. I also tried to set the encoding to UTF-8. Any idea?